# Adding parameter to Azure workbook for filtering data

Tags: azure, parameters, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have an azure workbook where I added a parameter to manipulate the display of data. the parameter is a dropdown parameter that should filter for "Pass" or a "Fail" records. the parameter is built from json where a value is linked to a label. when I save the workbook and try to filter nothing happens.

I added an parameter to the workbook see following screenshot:
[image]

When I filter with the parameter I don't see the associated data. Only the records with the value "pass" are displayed instead of records with value "Fail".See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Did you check that the resource you are working has a parameter `Fail` name and label?  @ferdy

Comment: how *exactly* are you "filtering with the parameter" ?  normally ou'd reference that value in  query like `| where Result == "{result}"` in the actual query content.  Workbooks parameters have to be referenced in the data sources/etc, they don't automatically hook up on similar names/columns (and in this case given it is a multi value parameter, it would be more like  `| where Result in ({result})` because you could select either or both values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary issue and you need to cross check below points to resolve it.

- Check that the labels `"Pass"` and `"Fail"` are accurately linked to the values `"Pass"` and `"Fail"` in your resource templates.
- Check to see if you've set a default value for the labels. If yes, make sure it isn't set to `"Pass"` by default, as this could cause it to only filter for `"Pass"` label entries.
- When adjusting parameter values, data visualizations may not update immediately. To reflect those, wait for some time, refresh the data/page and check it again.

After checked all the above, I tried to create a dropdown by selecting a new workbook, as showed. As I don't have any similar data like you, the output is as follows.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  Workbooks isn't based on "resource templates" so that bullet is meaningless here. "default value for the labels" doesn't make sense based on the OP's content.  "data visualizations may not update immediately" also isn't true.  If a data source references a parameter, changing that parameter value will cause the datasource to run again immediately.

Comment: Could you provide me a reference why "default value for the labels" doesn't make sense? so that I can explore more and update my answer. @JohnGardner

Comment: default value of the labels *where*?  do you mean somehow *in* the query?  if you did, the query coudl still filter on them, so it doesn't really make sense how it is worded.